# Running php artisan times out

Tags: exception, timeout, composer-php, laravel-artisan, laravel-4.2

I've inherited a Laravel 4.2 project and am performing some clean up.

When I run `php artisan` I get this:

```
[Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException] 
The process "php artisan clear-compiled" exceeded the timeout of 300 seconds.
```

I've tried to increase the timeout, but it still eventually throws the same exception.

This happens when I attempt to run any and all `artisan` commands both locally and in my VM (Homestead).

Running `composer install -o -vvv` shows the following stack trace after the timeout occurs (which is at the end during `php artisan clear-compiled`):

```
Exception trace:
 () at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:1190
 Symfony\Component\Process\Process->checkTimeout() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:361
 Symfony\Component\Process\Process->wait() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:203
 Symfony\Component\Process\Process->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Util/ProcessExecutor.php:68
 Composer\Util\ProcessExecutor->execute() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:223
 Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:95
 Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatchScript() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer.php:296
 Composer\Installer->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/UpdateCommand.php:172
 Composer\Command\UpdateCommand->execute() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:259
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:844
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:192
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:221
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:123
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:101
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/bin/composer:43
 require() at /usr/local/bin/composer.phar:24
```

Any ideas of what can be causing this? The only information I've seen is to increase the timeout for Composer, but this hasn't worked for me so far.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`php artisan something:test --timeout=0`

if this didnt work try to remove the vendor folder and run

`composer self-update` and `composer update`